# Using an array of numbers to add up to a specific number

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, sum, calculation

I've been trying to find out an efficient method of finding multiple numbers from an array that add up to a given number. In this instance I'm trying to find 3 numbers that total a target number.

I've got a basic working example below but unfortunately the recursive loop fails, it looks like there's an issue with it constantly looping. Ideally it would find the first possible answer and return it, but when it can't find an answer it gets stuck in the loop and breaks the browser.

## Warning: the below code will break due to a memory leak:

```js
let array = [5,6,3,3,6,67,2,2,6,7,7,2,1,3,4,5,67,7,4,2,5,6,3,3,6,67,2,2,6,7,7,2,1,3,4,5,67,7,4,2,5,6,3,3,6,67,2,2,6,7,7,2,1,3,4,5,67,7,4,2];

function findSums(arr, target, count) {
    var result = [];
    function recurse(start, leftOver, selection) {
        if (leftOver < 0) return; // failure
        if (leftOver === 0 && selection.length == count) {
            result.push(selection); // add solution
            return;
        }
        for (var i = start; i < arr.length; i++) {
            recurse(i, leftOver-arr[i], selection.concat(arr[i]));
        }
    }
    recurse(0, target, []);
    return result;
}
// Demo
$('#input').on('blur', function(e){
  let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  let result = findSums(array, value, 3);
  if(result.length > 0){
    $('#output').text(result[0]); 
  } else {
    $('#output').text('Nothing found');
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Input Number Below</h1>
<input id="input" type="number" />
<code id="output" ></code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it didn't break, when I tested, but still here are some tips:

You should set additional limitation to the count. You are making to much extra calls. When your function deals with really big sum, small numbers and small count it will call itself again until it reaches or overflows the desired sum, and only after that it will check current count. So you should add

```
if (selection.length > count) return;
```

Also. As I see there are many duplicates in your array, so I assume, that usage of the same number is allowed, but only if it is taken from another index. In your loop you are calling next `recurse` with the same start index. I think, you need

```
for (var i = start; i < arr.length; i++) {
    recurse(i + 1, leftOver-arr[i], selection.concat(arr[i]));
}
```

And finally. This will not influence the recursive part of an algorithm, but maybe you'd like to filter out same results, or filter out your array to remove all duplicates.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** sorry, missed the part about first possible solution. Here is the way to achieve this:

```
function recurse(start, leftOver, selection) {
  if (leftOver < 0) return false; // failure
  if (selection.length > count) return false;
  if (leftOver === 0 && selection.length == count) {
      result.push(selection); // add solution
      return true;
  }
  for (var i = start; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var res = recurse(i + 1, leftOver-arr[i], selection.concat(arr[i]));
      if (res) return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, I'll carry those extra tips over in the future, this is the first time I've had to do a recursive loop. I'll make sure to take out the duplicates for the purpose of the application :)